# vb.net Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: vb.net

i am declaring this variable as a date:

```
Dim fromdate as Date
```

inside a while loop when reading in a .csv file, i read this value:

```
Input(1, fromdate)
```

but if the value in the CSV file is blank i am getting an error saying

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

how can i set `fromdate` as todays date in vb.net (`Date.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`) if its blank in the .csv file?

Comment: `Input` is a really old backwards compatibility function - if you're writing new code, there is almost certainly a better way of doing so.  You may want to share some more of your code to get some better answers.

Comment: its old code, just the csv file has recently changed but currently there is no time to rewrite code, but this will be done in the future

Comment: Fair enough.  Is it definitely the `Input` line that's throwing that error?  [The docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tty8298b(v=vs.90).aspx) seem to indicate that it should only throw `IOException`

Comment: yeah, ive tried add an if statement below the input line for if its not a valid date but the error is definately showing on the input line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there should be a problem with the value you are trying to read. Maybe it's not there (as the error is mentioning).

Anyway you can try this code and catch the error and control it :

```
    Try
        Input(1, fromdate)
    Catch ex As IOException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        ' try to set the date in another way or choose the default value
    End Try
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tty8298b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> Exceptions :
>
> - IOException [52] : FileNumber does not exist.
> - IOException [54] : File mode is invalid.
>
> See the "Error number" column if you are upgrading Visual Basic 6.0 applications that use unstructured error handling. (You can compare the error number against the Number Property (Err Object).) However, when possible, you should consider replacing such error control with Structured Exception Handling Overview for Visual Basic.